# Rails: How can I make a condition to locate the enter button according to the chosen item

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to ask a naive question about making condition of the button,which can enter the right item.

I have the MVC of books and sections.
and for book       "has_many :sections"    for section"belongs_to :book"

so there are buttons in each line of the book list,called"enter the section page".
For example,I wanna click that button of book.1,so can I enter the section page of the book.1

The database of section have the column like "id,book_id,content..."

I have a view of section called sectionbybook,and I create a action in the sectionscontroller as follow:

```
    def sectionbybook
       @section=Section.find(:all, :conditions =>["book_id=?",params[:book_id])
    end
```

or make that book.select

but it doesn't work. I wanna know,how can I locate the action of the particular button of the item which I clicked,and enter the next page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use params[:id], please refer the below code.
    def sectionbybook
       @section=Section.find(:all, :conditions =>["book_id=?",params[:id])
    end

Thanks